# How to use suppressMessages() inside map()

Tags: r, purrr, suppressmessage

I made a function `my_fun()` which generates messages with the `message()` function. And also uses `pb$tick()` to track progress with `progress::progress_bar`.
I am running this function inside a `purrr::map()` call to iterate over a long list like: `map(my_list, my_fun)`. So the message is displayed a over and over.
I would like to suppress the message like 
`map(my_list, suppressMessages(my_fun))`
but it has no effect.

The call `suppressMessages(map(my_list, my_fun))` works but that suppresses the progress_bar as well.

Is there a convenient way to remove the messages without removing the `message()`  calls from `my_fun()`?

Answer (score 0):

Though you have not included any reproducible example for your use case, yet in my opinion, the following code using anonymous function style of `purrr` should work.

```
map(my_list, ~ suppressMessages(my_fun(.x)))
```

Do not forget to use twiddle `~` in above.